# Which script actually does automatic suspend of machine?

Tags: ssh, suspend, idle

Which particular script is activated upon inactivity of the system? How does the script know that system has been inactive for the configured duration?

I need the script, so that I can check if someone has logged on via SSH, and prevent the script from actually suspending the machine.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic suspend is now managed by [systemd-services](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/systemd-services), especially its [logind](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/logind.conf.5.html) manager.

From its man page:

```
DESCRIPTION
   systemd-logind is a system service that manages user logins. It is
   responsible for:

   ·   Keeping track of users and sessions, their processes and their idle
       state

   ·   Creating control groups for user processes

   ·   Providing PolicyKit-based access for users to operations such as
       system shutdown or sleep

   ·   Implementing a shutdown/sleep inhibition logic for applications

   ·   Handling of power/sleep hardware keys

   ·   Multi-seat management

   ·   Session switch management

   ·   Device access management for users

   ·   Automatic spawning of text logins (gettys) on virtual console
       activation and user runtime directory management
```

To check if a session is preventing your system from suspend, you can use the [`loginctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/loginctl.1.html) command:

1. to list the active sessions:

   ```
   $ loginctl list-sessions
      SESSION        UID USER             SEAT            
           c1        112 lightdm          seat0           
            2       1000 u                                
           c2       1000 u                seat0
   ```
2. to identify the remote sessions:

   ```
   $ loginctl session-status 2
          Since: lun. 2014-09-08 10:21:22 CEST; 2h 32min ago
         Leader: 2283 (sshd)
         Remote: sylvain-thinkpad-t430s.home
        Service: sshd; type tty; class user
          State: active
           Unit: session-2.scope
   ```

Comment: @bkd.online Could you please consider accepting this answer? I think it covers your question. Thanks.